# What is the use of openvpn?

Tags: ssh, openvpn

I have an ec2 instance running. I connect it via `ssh`. It looks good for me. Now my team lead asks me to set up an OpenVpn. I wonder why should I do this.

With the `ssh` command, I can connect to my ec2 instance and transfer the file. `ssh` is secure.

And creating a openvpn also going to allow me to transfer the file.

So what makes `openvpn` more powerful than `ssh`?

Comment: What reasons do your team give for requiring a VPN ?

Comment: They need to be more secure. This is why I got the doubt of why not `ssh` can be secure? But after reading the answers, I can convince myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this instance, the OpenVPN would be used to logically extend your LAN.  This would allow your devs to connect to the web server, database, etc. as if the EC2 instance was a computer plugged into your network.  The alternative is to tunnel everything through a SSH connection using port-forwarding. Each developer would have to manually set up their SSH client to do this and for each TCP port they wanted to connect to. Functionally, these two options are equivalent (and even use the same encryption technology).  But a VPN is generally easier for users to use because it "just works".